# $f: SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ show that $Im(f)=SL_4(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was struggling with the following problem (from linear algebra):

> Let $V$ be the vector space of the $2 \times 2$ matrices with real coefficients. Consider the action of the group $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $V$, namely for any matrix $T \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and for every matrx $A \in V$ we define $\Phi_T(A)=T\cdot A\cdot T^{-1}$. Prove that for every $T\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, $\Phi_T$ is an endomorphism of $V$. Then starting from a basis of $V$, write the corresponding homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to GL_4(\mathbb{R})$, then show that the image lies inside $SL_4(\mathbb{R})$

First of all. Does anybody know the origin of this problem? Is there a book with standard solutions to this kind of problem? And is my solution any good? Apparently it is generalizable to many more dimensions, giving a nontrivial result on the determinant of such matrices.
And what does it happen when the trace is $0$? Can we show an homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to SL_3(\mathbb{R})$ in the same way?

Comment: Dear lanzariel, The title of your question is misstated.  The image will lie in $SL_4$, but won't equal $SL_4$.  Regards,

Comment: Dear lanzariel, This is a special case of the theory of representations of Lie groups and algebraic groups.  There are many books that treat this theory; *Fulton and Harris* is one of my favourite introductions to the theory.  And yes, you can get a map to $SL_3$ in the same way.  Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Bbb k$ be a field, and let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\Bbbk$-vector space (of dimension $n$). The special linear group $SL(V)$ is generated [shear mappings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping). All shear mappings are conjugate in $GL(V)$, so that the linear maps "conjugation by a shear map" are conjugate as endomorphisms of $\mathrm{End}(V)$, and thus have the same determinant. If we prove tha conjugation by a shear mapping induces a linear map of determinant one on $\mathrm{End}(V)$, then from what precedes we see that conjugation by a map of determinant one has determinant one aswell.

I'll describe two paths to the result. The first is a direct computation in an appropriately chosen basis of $\mathrm{End}(V)$. The second approach is simpler and more formal : it uses the determinant and the fact that the square of a shear mapping is a shear mapping (or the identity in characteristic $2$).

### First proof

Let $u$ be a shear mapping. By definition there exists nonzero linear form $f:V\to \Bbbk$ and a nonzero vector $h\in H=\ker(f)$ such that for all $v\in V$
$$u(v)=v+f(v)h$$
Consider a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ of the form $(e_1,\dots,e_n)=(h_1,\dots,h_{n-2},h,x)$ where $h$ is as above, $f(x)=1$ and $(h_1,\dots,h_{n-2},h)$ is a basis of $H$. Then
$$\mathrm{Mat}(u;\mathcal{B})=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\\&&\ddots\\&&&1\\&&&&1&1\\&&&&&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Consider the basis $(E_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ associated to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ defined on basis elements by 
$$E_{i,j}(e_k)=\begin{cases}k=j:& e_i\\ k\neq j:&0\end{cases}$$
Then $u=\mathrm{id}+E_{n-1,n}$ and $u^{-1}=\mathrm{id}-E_{n-1,n}$; for any $i,j$
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
u\circ E_{i,j}\circ u^{-1} &=&(\mathrm{id}+E_{n-1,n})E_{i,j}(\mathrm{id}-E_{n-1,n})\\
&=&E_{i,j}+E_{n-1,n}E_{i,j}-E_{i,j}E_{n-1,n}-E_{n-1,n}E_{i,j}E_{n-1,n}\\
&=&
\begin{cases}
i\neq n,j\neq n-1:&E_{i,j}\\
i= n,j\neq n-1:&E_{n,j}+E_{n-1,j}\\
i\neq n,j= n-1:&E_{i,n-1}-E_{i,n}\\
i=n,j=n-1:&E_{n,n-1}+E_{n-1,n-1}-E_{n-1,n}-E_{n,n}
\end{cases}\\
&=&
\begin{cases}
i\neq n,j\neq n-1:&E_{i,j}\\
i= n,j\neq n-1:&E_{i,j}+\cdots\in X\\
i\neq n,j= n-1:&E_{i,j}+\cdots\in X\\
i=n,j=n-1:&E_{i,j}+\cdots\in Y
\end{cases}
\end{array}$$
where $X=\mathrm{Vect}(E_{i,j})_{i\neq n,j\neq n-1}$ and $Y=\mathrm{Vect}(E_{i,j})_{(i,j)\neq(n,n-1)}$, so that the matrix of conjugation by $u$, when represented in some basis obtained by ordering the vectors $(E_{i,j})_{i\neq n,j\neq n-1}\cup(E_{n,j})_{j\neq n-1}\cup(E_{i,n-1})_{i\neq n}\cup(E_{n,n-1})$ inside each set of parantheses is upper triangular with a diagonal made of ones.

### Second proof

Another line of reasoning goes as follows: we have a linear group action $\rho$ of $SL(V)$ on $\mathrm{End}(V)$
$$\rho:SL(V)\to GL(\mathrm{End}(V)),\quad u\mapsto u\circ-\circ u^{-1}$$
Which we may compose with the determinant
$$\det:GL(\mathrm{End}(V))\to\Bbbk^{\times}$$
Notice that the square of a shear mapping is either a shear mapping (if $\mathrm{char}(\Bbbk)\neq 2$) or the identity (if $\mathrm{char}(\Bbbk)=2$) so that for any shear mapping $u$
$$\det(\rho(u))^2=
\begin{cases}
\det(\rho(u))&\text{if }\mathrm{char}(\Bbbk)\neq 2\\
1 &\text{if }\mathrm{char}(\Bbbk)=2
\end{cases}$$
So that, in both cases (since $1=-1$ in characteristic $2$) $\det(\rho(u))=1$. The generation and conjugation argument from above then tells us that $\rho$ maps $SL(V)$ into 
$SL(\mathrm{End}(V))$.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to show the actual homomorphism. I found the matrix in $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ associated to the general matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, namely:
$$ \left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix} \right) \quad \text{with} \ ad-bc\neq0 $$
And it should be the following:
$$ \left( \begin{matrix}ad & -ac & bd &-bc\\ -ab & a^2 & -b^2 & ab \\ cd & -c^2 & d^2 & -cd\\ -bc & ac & -bd & ad\end{matrix}\right) $$

But honestly I find it a tedious task to look at its determinant to show that it is always $1$.

I found an alternative solution by looking at the abstract algebra behind it. We can compose the homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ with the homomorphism given by the determinant $GL_4(\mathbb{R}) \to (\mathbb{R^*}, \cdot)$. We get a new homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to (\mathbb{R^*}, \cdot)$. But I can prove that this homomorphism is trivial! [In this paper](http://math.berkeley.edu/~efuchs/250A/PSL2Rsimple.pdf) I found a proof that the only normal subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ are $\{\pm 1\}$ and the trivial ones. Given that the kernel must be a normal subgroup and that the matrix $$\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$$ must map to the identity since it has order $4$ we have that the whole group maps to the identity giving the thesis!

Comment: I would probably leave this as-is, but in the future please note that this is a bit improper. Your question is "is my proof correct?". Thus this is not an answer to your question, but instead should be in the question itself. Save the answer for comments on your solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question setter probably mean this. Consider the following ordered basis $\mathcal B$ of $V=M_2(\mathbb R)$.
$$
\mathcal B=\left\{
B_1=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},
\ B_2=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0},
\ B_3=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},
\ B_4=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}
\right\}.
$$
We can identify every $B=\pmatrix{a&c\\ b&d}\in V$ with the vector $\renewcommand{\vec}{\operatorname{vec}}\vec(B)=(a,b,c,d)^\top\in\mathbb R^4$ (this is known as the [vectorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) of a matrix). Now, for any $T\in SL_2(\mathbb R)$, the group action $B\mapsto TBT^{-1}$ is actually an automorphism. It follows that the image of $\mathcal B$ under the group action is still a basis of $V$. Consequently, the matrix
$$
f(T) = \left[\vec(TB_1T^{-1}),\vec(TB_2T^{-1}),\vec(TB_3T^{-1}),\vec(TB_4T^{-1})\right]
$$
lies inside $GL_4(\mathbb R)$. If one knows what a [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) is, one immediately sees that
$$
f(T)=(T^{-\top}\otimes T)
\underbrace{\left[\vec(B_1),\vec(B_2),\vec(B_3),\vec(B_4)\right]}_{=I_4}
=T^{-\top}\otimes T.
$$
By the properties of Kronecker product (see the above-linked Wikipedia entry), it is also obvious that $f$ is a group homomorphism from $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ to $GL_4(\mathbb R)$ and $\det f(T)=1$, i.e. $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subset SL_4(\mathbb R)$. Also, $f$ is injective. Therefore $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb R)$. This is probably why the last sentence in the question says that *"the image lies inside $SL_2(\mathbb R)$"*, if the $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ here is not a typo to $SL_4(\mathbb R)$.

The 4-by-4 matrix that you have shown is $T\otimes T^{-\top}$. So, it also works.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! But I do not understand what you "immediately see" since on Wikipedia I couldn't find anything like $T^{-T}$. What does it mean? And what is your real reference? Do you mean the inverse of the transpose?

Comment: @lanzariel For a square matrix $P$, the symbol $P^{-\top}$ is a (rather common, but not standard) shorthand for $(P^{-1})^\top=(P^\top)^{-1}$. For any three matrices $M,A,N$ such that the product $MAN$ is defined, we have $\operatorname{vec}(MAN)=(N^\top \otimes M)\operatorname{vec}(A)$. Thus $f(T)=T^{-\top}\otimes T$. And what do you mean by "real reference"? Real reference of what?

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear.
I mean that if you write: "see the above-linked Wikipedia entry" I expect to find your same notation in the "above-linked Wikipedia entry". Otherwise it means you are not really referring to that page.